# Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #<div/>

Tags: jquery

After updating from jquery 1.5 to 1.8 I get the following error:

```
Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #<div/>
```

Updating to 1.7 gives:

```
Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: >
```

Updating to 1.6 no error.

- How do I resolve this?
- Where do I start searching?
- Will I have to search in the code for: `"<div/>"`?

EDIT:
This is what Chrome tells me:

```
Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #<div/> base.js:4512
Sizzle.error             base.js:4512
tokenize                  base.js:4785
Sizzle.compile        base.js:4883
select     base.js:4973
select     base.js:5083
Sizzle       base.js:3912
jQuery.fn.extend.find      base.js:5171
jQuery.fn.jQuery.init       base.js:163
jQuery       base.js:44
SysElement.SysElement.Init        SysControls.js:1143
SysElement          SysControls.js:1179
SysListView.SysListView._ConstructTable       WebResource.axd:442
SysListView.SysListView._Init      WebResource.axd:661
SysListView     WebResource.axd:680
(anonymous function)       CRMAccounts.aspx:122
Sys$UI$DomEvent$addHandler.browserHandler
```

Comment: But is there a way to find the error? Cause now when using Chrome or FF, it just shows the error alert in jquery. Not the issue.

Comment: Perhaps just the part which is causing the error? I don't think anyone will be able to help based on what is currently in the question.

Comment: Use the Console in Chrome Developer Tools - this should give you the stack trace for the error

Comment: Place the whole message in the question above.

Comment: Do you have `$('#<div/>')` somewhere in your code? o_O

Comment: searched through all code, haven't found div/ at all

Comment: I'd take a look here - (anonymous function) CRMAccounts.aspx:122 - first.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error seems to be coming from Sizzle, which is used by jquery to handle element selectors such as `$('#mydiv')`. It looks like you are using an invalid selector like `$('#<div/>')` somewhere. Perhaps you are trying to select a div using its id? - if that is the case then replace `<div/>` with the id of the div element. eg

```
<div id="mydiv">blah</div>

$('#mydiv').html('content');
```

Comment: i did find: selection.ReplaceHtml($("<div/>").append($("<a/>").attr("href", 'DocEdit.aspx?ID=' + value[0]).html(selection.GetHtml())).html());

and:
this._listViewLocation = new SysElement("<div/>");

But if i comment those, i still get the error.

Comment: Found the solution.
We use our own System elements.
<div/> was not allowed anymore.
I changed it to: <div></div> and now the error is gone and everything works how it should be.

Thank you all for the suggestions!

Comment: For reference as well: http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#jquery-htmlstring-versus-jquery-selectorstring

Answer (score 0):

It might happen that you have accidentally typed any character in between the  tag. e.g.,

```
<div"> instead of <div>
```