# Jquery Error : Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: <div>

Tags: jquery, html

I am calling and loading html file. It file contains 3 `<div>` tags. The first one is loaded in one container. The second one in another and so the third one. Here is the code of my ajax query

```
$.ajax(
                {  
                    url: 'files/' + href,                       
                    async: true,
                    success: function(XML){
                        console.log("It's a success");
                        var xml = XML;
                        var desc = $(xml).find("div").eq(0).html();
                        $("#listView .list_detail:eq(0)").html(desc);
                        var rule = $(xml).find("div").eq(1).html();
                        $("#listView .list_detail:eq(1)").html(rule);
                        var em = $(xml).find("div").eq(2).html();
                        $("#listView .list_detail:eq(2)").html(em);
                        $("#listView .list_detail:eq(0)").slideDown();
                    }
});
```

But I'm getting an error on loading of that html file.

`Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: <div>`

and every html file is like

```
<div> the list
    <ul>3 rounds
    <li>first round
    <li>second round 
    </ul>
</div> 
<div> data data </div>
<div> data data </div>`
```

What's wrong? I didn't get.

Comment: what type of object is XML, is it a json?

Comment: it is a simple html. Not xml. 3 <div> only..

Comment: can you add that exact content?

Comment: added the details. Can you get it?

Comment: you can't do find on the array of elements with selectors. just remove find and it will work. $(xml)[index].

Comment: got the error : Uncaught TypeError: Object #<HTMLDivElement> has no method 'html'

Comment: Maybe a duplicate of [Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #<div/>](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11982184/uncaught-error-syntax-error-unrecognized-expression-div)

Comment: just do $($(xml)[index]).html().. forgot to mention another $

Comment: tried that also.. not working..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$.ajax(
                {  
                    url: 'files/' + href,                       
                    async: true,
                    success: function(XML){
                        console.log("It's a success");
                        var xml = XML;
                        var desc = $($(xml)[0]).html();
                        $("#listView .list_detail:eq(0)").html(desc);
                        var rule = $($(xml)[1]).html();
                        $("#listView .list_detail:eq(1)").html(rule);
                        var em = $($(xml)[2]).html();
                        $("#listView .list_detail:eq(2)").html(em);
                        $("#listView .list_detail:eq(0)").slideDown();
                    }
});
```

Comment: no way.. since its simple string should be working. what is the error?

Comment: same error. As i've described in the question. I'm finding the error from 3 days. Still no success. :(

Comment: Is there anything with the `"` in that file ? or some other characters?

Comment: containing 3 div elements.

Comment: can you see the response in browser console with console.log(XML) and see is that outputs string or not.

Comment: Yes, it prints the whole file. And then under it the same error :(

Comment: As it is a bit private I'm writing all the tags except the data between that is the string only.
`
<div>
3 rounds
<ul>
<li>item1</li>
<li>item3</li>
<li>item3</li>


</ul>
</div>

<div>
<ul>
<li>line3</li>
<li>line1</li>
<li>line2</li>

</ul>
</div>

<div>
Name and number
</div>
`

Comment: oh.. is this content is wrapped by other tags like html, body etc?

Comment: okay, do wrap your three div with another div and try your own code. The way your code has written need a wrapper.

Comment: ok.. then do i need to use find("div") ?. because i'll wrap 3 div's in anothe div..

Comment: I added the wrapper before. but it was not eble to find the second div bcoze it finds all the div inside the first. But finally, got it ! thanks man. I was working on this one from the 3 days ! got it.. Now used this syntax : `var desc = $($(xml)[0]).find("div").eq(0).html();` and eq(1) and eq(2) .. got it ! thanks once again.. :D

Comment: make sure there are no spaces between closing and opening div.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this and check if this work...

```
$.ajax(
                {  
                    url: 'files/' + href,                       
                    async: true,
                    success: function(data){
                        console.log("It's a success");
                        var resultData= $(data);
                        var desc = $(resultData).find("div").eq(0).html();
                        $("#listView .list_detail:eq(0)").html(desc);
                        var rule = $(resultData).find("div").eq(1).html();
                        $("#listView .list_detail:eq(1)").html(rule);
                        var em = $(resultData).find("div").eq(2).html();
                        $("#listView .list_detail:eq(2)").html(em);
                        $("#listView .list_detail:eq(0)").slideDown();
                    }
});
```

If it is not working then let me know what result you are getting for following code

```
$.ajax(
                {  
                    url: 'files/' + href,                       
                    async: true,
                    success: function(data){
                        alert(""success); // is it showing this alert box?
                        var resultData= $(data);
                        alert(resultData.length);//is it showing this length properly?
                        var desc = $(resultData).find("div").eq(0).html();
                        alert(desc.length);//is it showing this length properly?
                        $("#listView .list_detail:eq(0)").html(desc);
                        alert($("#listView .list_detail:eq(0)").length);//is it showing this length properly?
                        var rule = $(resultData).find("div").eq(1).html();
                        $("#listView .list_detail:eq(1)").html(rule);
                        var em = $(resultData).find("div").eq(2).html();
                        $("#listView .list_detail:eq(2)").html(em);
                        $("#listView .list_detail:eq(0)").slideDown();
                    }
});
```

Comment: It is just throwing the first alert success. Than console shows the same error.

Answer (score 0):

It should be

```
$.ajax(
                {  
                    url: 'files/' + href,                       
                    async: true,
                    success: function(data){
                        console.log("It's a success");
                        var resultData= $(data);
                        var desc = $(resultData).find("div").eq(0).html();
                        $("#listView .list_detail:eq(0)").html(desc);
                        var rule = $(resultData).find("div").eq(1).html();
                        $("#listView .list_detail:eq(1)").html(rule);
                        var em = $(resultData).find("div").eq(2).html();
                        $("#listView .list_detail:eq(2)").html(em);
                        $("#listView .list_detail:eq(0)").slideDown();
                    }
});
```

and HTML : you forgot to close `</li>`

```
<div> the list
    <ul>3 rounds
    <li>first round</li>
    <li>second round </li>
    </ul>
</div> 
<div> data data </div>
<div> data data </div>`
```

Comment: yes. My file contains `</li>` also.. and it also didn't work. Even I've tried <br></br> .. but that also didn't work.