# Getting Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying get the value of `Contact_LastName` from the HTML pasted below but I am getting the following error

```
Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: div #u1@g.com
```

Javascript :

```
 $('.rdContact').off("click").on("click", function (e) {
                              e.preventDefault();
                              $(this).next("div").toggle();  

                              $('.btn-success').off('click').on('click', function (e) { 
                                 e.preventDefault();
                                 var divId = $(this).closest('div').parent().attr('id');
                                 var lnameval = $("div #"+ divId).closest('#Contact_LastName').val();
                                 alert(lnameval);  
                              });

                          });
```

HTML :

```
<input type="radio" class="rdContact" name="ContactGroup" value="u1@g.com" style="">

<div class="row" id="u1g.com" style="display: none;">
        <div class="col-md-6">

            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-3 control-label">
                    <label>Last Name:</label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <input class="form-control pr_input defaultText quiet reqrd" id="Contact_LastName" maxlength="50" name="ContactLastName" type="text" value="">
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-3 control-label">
                    <label>First Name:</label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <input class="form-control defaultText quiet reqrd" id="Contact_FirstName" maxlength="50" name="ContactFirstName" type="text" value="">
                </div>
            </div>               
        </div>


        <div class="modal-footer">                 
            <input type="button" value="Add Contact" id="btnSaveContact" class="btn btn-success">
            <input type="button" value="Cancel" id="btnCancelContact" class="btn btn-default">    
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11982184/uncaught-error-syntax-error-unrecognized-expression-div

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because `u1@g.com` is not a valid value for an element's ID, so jQuery is unable to parse your selector.

From the [HTML4 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/types.html#type-id):

> > ID and NAME tokens must begin with a letter ([A-Za-z]) and may be followed by any number of letters, digits ([0-9]), hyphens ("-"), underscores ("_"), colons (":"), and periods (".").

The solution is to use a valid value for your ID.

[See also](https://stackoverflow.com/a/79022/1945651)

Re: your comment below, you are getting `undefined` because you are using [`closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) wrong (please follow that link to find out what `closest()` actually does).

I'm willing to bet that you have the `id` `Contact_LastName` in multiple places in your page, and that is a big problem because ids have to be unique.

I am also very curious why you are selecting the `row` div and retrieving its ID, just so that you can use that ID to re-select it in the next line.

Instead of your current approach, get rid of your duplicate IDs and use this:

```
$('.btn-success').off('click').on('click', function (e) { 
    e.preventDefault();
    var row = $(this).closest(".row");
    var lnameval = row.find("input[name='ContactLastName']").val();
    alert(lnameval);  
});
```

Comment: Thank you. now I am not getting the error but the value for lnameval is returned as Undefined.

Comment: You r absolutely right there are multiple "Contact_LastName" in my page.  Because this form is dynamically generated I need to first get hold of the parent and then capture the firstname, lastname and so on.  Your approach worked great. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The error is coming from Sizzle, which is used by jQuery to parse the element selector.

Your div has a strange id: `u1@g.com`. Try using ids without `@`.

Comment: Thank you. now I am not getting the error but the value for lnameval is returned as Undefined.