# JavaScript Error: Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: input#comment_1/2

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc

I am getting java script error like :

```
Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: input#comment_1/2
```

the only `comment` keyword i have used in cshtml file is in this line code.

```
 <input placeholder="Enter your comments" type="text" style="width:800px;" id="comment_@item/@kpi.Id" name="comment_@item/@kpi.Id" />
```

i did not use `comment` keyword any where in java script, But i am getting this error.
Thanks.

Comment: which script is throwing the said error

Comment: If you are using the id as a selector then you need to escape those special characters like `'#comment_\\@item\\/\\@kpi\\.Id'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening because comment_@item/@kpi.Id is not a valid value for an element's ID, so jQuery is unable to parse your selector.

From the HTML4 spec:

> ID and NAME tokens must begin with a letter ([A-Za-z]) and may be
>   followed by any number of letters, digits ([0-9]), hyphens ("-"),
>   underscores ("_"), colons (":"), and periods (".").

The solution is to use a valid value for your ID. [see answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27051849/getting-uncaught-error-syntax-error-unrecognized-expression)