# Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: input[@type=submit]

Tags: javascript, requirejs, r.js

I got this exception in some website who injected my js plugin,

But some are working perfectly,

I'm guessing I miss to put some js dependency in the plugin `dadasay.min.js`

However, is it possible to conflict with other libraries?

dadasay.min.js:11243 `Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: input[@type=submit]`

source code : http://dadasay.com/plugin/v1/js/dadasay.min.js

## Update

It seems that the required js libraries in `http://dadasay.com/plugin/v1/js/dadasay.min.js` are polluting the host website. How could I prevent my plugin to pollute the host websites? Cuz, there are lots of websites will embedded this plugin.

```
{
    name: "app.main.js",
    mainConfigFile: 'app.main.js',
    out: "../js/dadasay.min.js",
    optimize: 'none',
    preserveLicenseComments: false,
    wrap: true,
    paths: {
        jqLib: './jquery',
        requireLib: './require'
    },
    include: [ 'jqLib','requireLib', 'app.main' ],
    insertRequire: ["app.main"],
}
```

Comment: Error is clear from `input[@type=submit]`

Answer (score 1):

In your error

> Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression:
>   input[@type=submit]

in this `input[@type=`submit`]` just Remove the `@` and add `'sumbit'` quote to `submit` to solve your problem.

Note that quote marks are also required.

[See the API reference for the attribute equals selector.](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/)

## Importnat Note :

XPath-like attribute selectors were removed in jQuery.

## See :

Here is simple [Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27051849/getting-uncaught-error-syntax-error-unrecognized-expression)

## Conclusion :

> ID and NAME tokens must begin with a letter ([A-Za-z]) and may be
>   followed by any number of letters, digits ([0-9]), hyphens ("-"),
>   underscores ("_"), colons (":"), and periods (".").

you have to `remove @` and give the value to quote `'value'`.

Comment: Hi the bug is only from this page, I don't know where comes this line ` input[@type=submit]` , Any idea to skip or fix the bug in a short way? https://www.cool3c.com/node/106226

Comment: @newBike Let I try to change it but It take some time to find it.

Comment: @newBike now you get the idea why this error is come.

Comment: Hi, pls see my update, Cus the buggy code is from host website, so I could NOT change their code. I need to fix my js plugin, do you have any idea to avoid polluting the global namespace. maybe they are using the deprecated jQUERY lib